# wxPython - Adjusting RadioBox label position

Tags: wxpython

I am adding a RadioBox to my toolbar in order to switch between some modes of operation for my GUI.

```
box = wx.RadioBox(toolbar, -1, 'Mode',
               choices=["Test 1 ", "Test 2 "],
               name='Mode', style=wx.RA_SPECIFY_COLS)
toolbar.AddControl(box)
```

This works, but the label "Mode" is on the top left of the RadioBox. How can I centre this label? It looks out of place when it's off to the side. As a long shot, I tried adding the wx.ALIGN_CENTRE style, but that was no help.

Lastly, the edges of the box are right on the end of the text. If I don't add a space at the end of the choice, the box appears too small. Is this normal?

Comment: have you tried using a tool like http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/ to achive what you want?

Comment: I have not. Is it useful at all? I noticed the last stable release was 5 years ago.

Comment: Yeah it is very useful. I'm fairly certain they've released versions more recently than that. I'm using the RC version and haven't encountered any problems.